# Printing results of git repo

Tags: git, github

I am working on the code for an engineering project, and I am being asked to develop a written portion for a document that contains the code I have written.  I am wondering if there are any tools that will make code formatted nicely while also including information from the git commits, for example git blame with code coloring and nice printing.

Answer (score 0):

You can start web interface for Git, use `git blame` (and other features) there and use [part of] HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

[highlight(1)](http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/highlight/en/highlight.php) (`brew install highlight` on your [Homebrew-equipped Mac](https://brew.sh/)) is what you're looking for.  You can `git blame` a file, pipe it to `highlight`, and stash the output in a file.

```
git blame foo.php | highlight --syntax php > foo.php.html && open foo.php.html
```

on my system produces good results.

[enscript(1)](https://www.markkurossi.com/genscript/) is the simplest way to highlight code and it's installed on most Mac & Linux boxes.  I use something like `enscript -E --color -C --mark-wrapped-lines=arrow` which gives syntax highlighting, color, line numbers, and wrapping of long lines.  The downside is it doesn't seem to handle having git-blame output piped into it.

See also: [source-highlight(1)](https://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/)